# django-oscar multiple custom products

Tags: django-oscar

Is there a way to add multiple custom products with django-oscar?

From the documentation section [How to customise models](http://docs.oscarcommerce.com/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_models.html), adding a single field to the product model is shown.

However, if for example I had two different products DVDs and Books.  DVDs would have the fields director and length and books would have the fields Author and pages. If I wanted to sub type those in the database. How would I go about doing this?

The documentation says

> You should inherit from AbstractProduct as above to alter behaviour for all your products. Further subclassing is not
>   recommended, because using methods and attributes of concrete
>   subclasses of Product are not available unless explicitly casted to
>   that class. To model different classes of products, use ProductClass
>   and ProductAttribute instead.

But I don't see an example of how to do that.

Comment: Why do you want a custom "class" for your products, when you can achieve what you are suggesting by simply creating different `ProductClass`es? See the docs for [how to model your catalogue](http://docs.oscarcommerce.com/en/latest/topics/modelling_your_catalogue.html).

Comment: It's a requirement.  I cannot save the attributes into an attributes table.  I need to create a database table for each product that I have that contains the properties of that product

Answer (score 0):

I am not comfortable with whatever idea you have (table for each product type), since Oscar does not recommend it this way, and it would likely err when displaying / handling such products requiring you to change / customize a lot of functionality.

If you really want access to product type classes (like `DVD`, `Book`), then I'd recommend you first add the products (of such product types) via a migration, then create utility classes that actually access `ProductClass`.

e.g.

**migration**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import sys
from csv import DictReader
from django.db import migrations
from oscar.core.loading import get_model


def create_products_castrol(app, schema_editor):
    ProductAttribute = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductAttribute')
    ProductCategory = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductCategory')
    ProductClass = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductClass')
    StockRecord = get_model('partner', 'StockRecord')
    Category = get_model('catalogue', 'Category')
    Product = get_model('catalogue', 'Product')
    Partner = get_model('partner', 'Partner')

    partner = Partner.objects.get(name='Default Partner')

    # Create product class for Books
    product_class = ProductClass.objects.create(
        name='Books',
        requires_shipping=False,
        track_stock=False
    )
    print("Created product class -", product_class)

    # Add necessary class attributes
    author_attr = ProductAttribute.objects.create(
        product_class=product_class,
        name='Author',
        code='author',
        type=ProductAttribute.TEXT,
        required=True
    )
    print("Created product attribute -", author_attr)

    # Create products
    with open('/app/data/raw/products.csv') as csvfile:
        products = list(DictReader(csvfile))
    for product in products:
        print('Creating product -', product['title'])
        product_category = Category.objects.filter(name=product['category'])
        pr = Product.objects.create(
            structure=Product.STANDALONE,
            upc=product['upc'],
            title=product['title'],
            description=product['description'],
            product_class=product_class
        )
        print('\tCreated product')
        # Categories
        ProductCategory.objects.create(
            category=product_category[0],
            product=pr
        )
        print('\tAdded category -', product_category[0])
        # Attributes
        if product.get('author'):
            author_attr.save_value(pr, product['author'])
        print('\tAdded attribute values')
        # Stock
        StockRecord.objects.create(
            product=pr,
            partner=partner,
            partner_sku=pr.upc,
            price_excl_tax=product['retail_price'],
            price_retail=product['retail_price'],
            cost_price=product['cost_price']
        )
        print('\tAdded stock record')


def delete_products_castrol(app, schema_editor):
    ProductClass = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductClass')
    Product = get_model('catalogue', 'Product')

    with open('/app/data/raw/products.csv') as csvfile:
        products = list(DictReader(csvfile))

    for product in products:
        Product.objects.filter(upc=product['upc']).delete()

    product_class = ProductClass.objects.get(name='Books')
    product_class.delete()
    # everything else cascades nicely

    Attribute = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductAttribute')
    Attribute.objects.filter(code='title', product_class=product_class
                    ).delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('catalogue', '0001_initial'),
        ('partner', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_products,
                             reverse_code=delete_products),
    ]
```

**Your code where you need to access Books and their attributes**

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model

ProductClass = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductClass')

BooksClass = ProductClass.objects.get(name='Books')
books = BooksClass.products.all()

for book in books:
    print(book.attr.author)
```

And just like `author`, you can add various other attributes. There are various types of attributes you can add, see [source](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py#L722).